# Dropdown Menu doesn't work inside navigation bar but works outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a dropdown-menu to my navigation bar. But when i click the dropdown it doesn't show me the menu.It the menu doesn't drop down. I have looked for solutions there are other related questions. But those were code-specific problems are not relevant to my code.

If i test the dropdown code taking it outside of the navgar it works. But inside the navbar it doesn't. Can anyone please help me? If you need help regarding reading this whole or need any kind of explanation, please ask.It is i who needs help.Thanks in advance.

So here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
//This is the part of dropdown//
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS i am applying to it:

```
<style>
  .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
  }

  .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
  }

  .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

  .show {display:block;}

  body{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }

      /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
      .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 100% ;
        height: 30px;
      }
      .navbarw3 {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
   .main {
      margin-top: 40px;  Add a top margin to avoid content overlay 
      }

      /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
      .row.content {height: 565px}

      /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
      .sidenav {
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
      footer {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .sidenav {
          height: auto;
          padding: 15px;
        }
        .row.content {height:auto;} 
      }
    </style>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>
window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to write any js for bootstrap dropdowns. Just include their js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your css classes that you used in your HTML, I assue you are using bootstrap. In that case, you really don't need to add any javascript for working with dropdown menu. make sure you linked the bootstrap css and js file in your page and then, just change the html to something like this :

```
<nav class="navbar justify-content-center navbar-expand-lg blackBg">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Gallery
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu blackBg">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Smiles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Cry's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Videos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Choreography</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/dmkh8xj1/

Comment: Thanks Emad for your effort. Your dropdown navbar works totally fine and gives me what i want. But still when i put this code in my project , the dropdown stops working. I guess i gotta give up on a dropdown. I would rather have a plain navbar.Thanks again.